# Cannot access check variable; it displays [object Object] in html( angular 7)

Tags: angular, typescript

My type script file

```
check:any=(this.myForm.get('Postpaid_comission'));
```

My html file

```
 <h3> {{check }}</h3>
 <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="Postpaid_credit_limit">Postpaid credit limit:</label>
 <div class="col-sm-10">
   <input type="text" formControlName="Postpaid_credit_limit" class="form-control" >
 </div>
```

Comment: try this {{check | json }} . check is an object that's why HTML shows [object object] use either JSON pipe to view object otherwise you can access  value using the dot operator

Comment: try check:any=(this.myForm.get('Postpaid_comission')).value, You need to use value property when your trying to access your form controls values

Answer (score 0):

You need to access `value` property on the control. This will return the value of the control.

```
check:any = this.myForm.get('Postpaid_comission').value;
```

Also based on the html you have provided, your control name is `Postpaid_credit_limit`, not `Postpaid_comission`.

Answer (score 0):

try

`check:any=(this.myForm.get('Postpaid_comission')).value`,

You need to use value property when your trying to access your form controls values

Answer (score 0):

In case you still want to keep `check` as a `FormControl` you can access the value in the template like this:

```
<h3> {{check.value }}</h3>
```

if the value of check is undefined at some point, you can use the safe navigation operator `?` like this:

```
<h3> {{check?.value }}</h3>
```